# Unity3D: Return value with a Delegate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates, return-value

I want to be able to get the return values from all the methods in my delegate. This is the code I have written in c#.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public static class DelagetsAndEvents {

        public delegate int UnitEventHandler(string _unit);
        public static event UnitEventHandler unitSpawn;

        public static int UnitSpawn(string _unit)
        {
            if(unitSpawn != null)
            {
                unitSpawn(_unit);
            }

            // here I want to return 1 + 2 from Planet/UnitSpawn and SolarSystem/UnitSpawn
            // is it possible to run a foreach on every method in the delegate and add their returns?

            return (method 1's return value) + (method 2's return value) (Or both seperately, that would be even better)
        }
    }

    public class Planet {

        public Planet()
        {
            DelagetsAndEvents.unitSpawn += UnitSpawn;
        }

        int UnitSpawn(string _unit)
        {
            Debug.Log("yo");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public class SolarSystem{

        public SolarSystem()
        {
            DelagetsAndEvents.unitSpawn += UnitSpawn;
        }

        int UnitSpawn(string _unit)
        {
            Debug.Log("bla");
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the delegate has a return type of int. Then the methods I put into my delegate also have the return type of int. One of them return 1 and the other one return 2. Is there a way to get those results to the location where I execute my delegate? That will be here:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestDelagets : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        SolarSystem s = new SolarSystem();
        Planet p = new Planet();
        string g = "";
        int i = DelagetsAndEvents.UnitSpawn(g);
        Debug.Log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in the "regular" .NET framework, you could use `Delegate.GetInvocationList`. For example, to combine that with LINQ:

```
// Note: do all of this after checking that unitSpawn is non-null...

var results = unitSpawn.GetInvocationList()
                       .Cast<UnitEventHandler>()
                       .Select(d => d(_unit))
                       .ToList();
```

I don't know offhand whether that will work with Unity, but I'd hope it would...

If the LINQ part doesn't work, you could use:

```
var invocations = unitSpawn.GetInvocationList();
var results = new int[invocations.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < invocations.Length; i++)
{
    results[i] = ((UnitEventHandler)invocations[i]).Invoke(_unit);
}
```

Comment: Linq does work in Unity but is one of those things, Unity devs recommend to avoid. It has been reported to fail on iOS. Not sure if still faulty.

Comment: @Everts Maybe that is something that had changed in last couple years, but Linq is currently absolutely fine in Unity.

Comment: It may have been improved but there was a time when also new on iOS would cause trouble. This was due to AOT vs JIT compilation. But they may have fixed it with some build magic.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention that you would need to get the added value or the two separate values, I would choose a different approach.

You could use Linq but Unity recommends to avoid it. Most likely due to the process of serialization between C++ and C# and GC.

You could store your methods in an array of actions. Then you can either get the full amount, or one by one with a basic foreach loop.

```
public class DelegateContainer : IDisposable{
    private IList<Func<string, int>> container = null;
    public DelegateContainer(){
        this.container = new List<Func<string,int>>();
    }
    public void Dispose(){
         this.container.Clear();
         this.container = null;
    }
    public bool AddMethod(Func<string, int> func){
       if(func != null && this.container.Contains(func) == false){
           this.container.Add(func);
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
    public bool RemoveMethod(Func<string, int>func){
       if(func != null && this.container.Contains(func) == true){
           this.container.Remove(func);
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
    public int GetFullValue(){
       int total = 0;
       foreach(var meth in this.container){
           if(meth != null) { total += meth(""); }
       }
       return total;
    }
    public IEnumerable<int> GetAllValues(){
        IList <int> list = new List<int>();
        foreach(var meth in this.container){
           if(meth != null) { list.Add(meth("");); }
       }
       return list as IEnumerable<int>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! It helped alot. I solved it with the folowing code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public static class DelagetsAndEvents {

    public delegate int UnitEventHandler(string _unit);
    public static event UnitEventHandler unitSpawn;

    public static int[] UnitSpawn(string _unit)
    {
        if(unitSpawn != null)
        {
            unitSpawn(_unit);
        }



        System.Delegate[] funcs = unitSpawn.GetInvocationList();
        int[] TIntArray = new int[funcs.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < funcs.Length; ++i)
        {
            TIntArray[i] = (int) funcs[i].DynamicInvoke(_unit);


        }

        return TIntArray;
    }
}

public class Planet {

    public Planet()
    {
        DelagetsAndEvents.unitSpawn += UnitSpawn;
    }

    int UnitSpawn(string _unit)
    {
        Debug.Log("yo");
        return 1;
    }
}

public class SolarSystem{

    public SolarSystem()
    {
        DelagetsAndEvents.unitSpawn += UnitSpawn;
    }

    int UnitSpawn(string _unit)
    {
        Debug.Log("bla");
        return 2;
    }
}
```

and:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections;

public class TestDelagets : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        SolarSystem s = new SolarSystem();
        Planet p = new Planet();
        string g = "";
        int[] i = DelagetsAndEvents.UnitSpawn(g);

        foreach(int f in i)
        {
            Debug.Log(f);
        }
    }
}
```